# Values not being assigned to array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays which are populated from two separate `api` requests.

```
protected $playerDetails = ['name' => [], 'role' => [], 'donations' => [], 'donationsReceived' => [], 'lastSeen' => []];

protected $warDetails = ['name' => [], 'warCollectionBattles' => [], 'warCardsEarned' => [], 'allocatedFinalBattles' => [], 'numberOfFinalBattlesPlayed' => [], 'warFinalBattleWin' => []];
```

Originally I had these 2 separate arrays as the data returned from both api requests has different indexes but as they share a common value `name` I am trying to refactor both arrays into one array.

```
protected $playerDetails = ['name' => [], 'role' => [], 'donations' => [], 'donationsReceived' => [], 'lastSeen' => [], 'warCollectionBattles' => [], 'warCardsEarned' => [], 'allocatedFinalBattles' => [], 'numberOfFinalBattlesPlayed' => [], 'warFinalBattleWin' => []];
```

So far I have the following code, which is working up until I try to assign  `$this->playerDetails['warFinalBattleWin']` but I am uncertain to why this isn't assigning like any other variable would be assigned.

```
//gets the index of the playerDetails aray
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($this->playerDetails); $i++) {
     //gets the index of the data from the api response
     for ($x=0; $x <= count($warArr['participants'])-1 ; $x++){
        //this outputs the name and wins as expected
        echo $warArr['participants'][$x]['name'] ;
        echo $warArr['participants'][$x]['wins'] . "<BR>";
        //checks that the name from the playerDetails array matches the name from the api response at each index
        if($this->playerDetails['name'][$i] == $warArr['participants'][$x]['name']){
            $this->playerDetails['warFinalBattleWin'][$i] = $warArr['participants'][$x]['wins'];
           }
        }
        break;
    }

//this outputs an empty array
print_r($this->playerDetails['warFinalBattleWin']);
```

Also would someone be able to explain why on this line

`for ($x=0; $x <= count($warArr['participants'])-1 ; $x++){`

I have to subtract 1 from the count of the array? If I don't do this I get an undefined offset notice such as

```
  Undefined offset: (value of count($warArr['participants']) )
```

Comment: When using <= in a for loop, it's to count - 1. If you use < then, no -1 is needed. `count` returns number of elements and arrays always start at 0.

Comment: Are you sure you want `break;` in there?

Comment: Your `break;` do the following: `loop 1... break;... end of code...` remove your `break;` to take a look whats the output.

Comment: @NigelRen If I omit `break;` I get some values assigned so $this->playerDetails['warFinalBattleWin'] looks like this  `Array ( [0] => 0 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [6] => 1 [8] => 0 [9] => 1 [10] => 1 )` but it should have 24 values.

Comment: How can name be an array? Can you put some dump data in your arrays?

Comment: I agree with @NigelRen about the `break` (perhaps it should be inside the `if` if it's needed at all) and I'm also wondering if `$this->playerDetails['warFinalBattleWin'][$i] = $warArr['participants'][$x]['wins'];` should actually be an array merge i.e. `$this->playerDetails['warFinalBattleWin'][$i] = array_merge($this->playerDetails['warFinalBattleWin'][$i],$warArr['participants'][$x]['wins']);`?

Comment: @Nick I can't use array merge because `$warArr['participants'][$x]['wins']` isn't an array. If I place the `break` inside the `if` I am unable to access all of the data from `$warArr['participants']`

Comment: @Sabathaon good to see you figured it out, you should accept your answer.

Comment: @Nick Thanks! I intend to but I need to wait 20 hours after I posted the answer before I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first for loop where I was getting the index for each player from the `playerDetails` array I was getting the count of the first dimension of this array when I should have been using count on `$this->playerDetails['name']` and then removing the `break`

So the working code looks like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->playerDetails['name']); $i++) {
    for ($x=0; $x < count($warArr['participants']) ; $x++){
         if($this->playerDetails['name'][$i] == $warArr['participants'][$x]['name']){
            $this->playerDetails['warFinalBattleWin'][$i] = $warArr['participants'][$x]['wins'];
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: If you find solution to your problem and post it as answer - great! please mark your answer as accepted (the grey "v' mark at the left of the post)

Comment: @dWinder I intend to but I need to wait 20 hours after I posted the answer before I can accept it.